# Intellij Error Hover

Tags: intellij-idea

When I hover over an error in intellij the normal error hover is displayed and looks like this:

[image]

Immediately after (around 1 second later and normally before I have a chance to read it...) I am greeted with this error hover instead...

[image]

How do I disable the second error hover from displaying?

Thanks.

Comment: You're in a debug context in with the second error on some sort of break point, aren't you?

Comment: Nope, the application wasn't running or paused. I was just browsing the source.

Comment: @Makoto I know this was a while ago but you are right, you should post it as an answer so I can accept it. If you have the debug window and hover over errors it changes to the second popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You're in a debug context

Yup I was in a debug context and this was causing the popup.